# Adapting Identity framework database into another custom database. Database first (Hash Issue)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to Implement Microsoft's Identity Framework (IF) into my Web site. I designed the database in such a way the framework would recognize the structure and work around it. But when I register an email all though  it does receive the data properly, the IF hasher doesn't work. There's an error implying that the ApplicationUser is not on the context, but the controller recieves data, on debug I can see the email and password. but on this line

```
var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

Seems to be looking for a value in my model that it's not there.

Thus I believe the issue is on the table AspNetUsers, is there a hidden property I missed?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers] (
[Id]                   NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
[Email]                NVARCHAR (256) NULL,
[EmailConfirmed]       BIT            NOT NULL,
[PasswordHash]         NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Password] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
[SecurityStamp]        NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[PhoneNumber]          NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[PhoneNumberConfirmed] BIT            NOT NULL,
[TwoFactorEnabled]     BIT            NOT NULL,
[LockoutEndDateUtc]    DATETIME       NULL,
[LockoutEnabled]       BIT            NOT NULL,
[AccessFailedCount]    INT            NOT NULL,
[UserName]             NVARCHAR (256) NOT NULL,
[Login] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[CreationDate] [datetime] NULL,
[ApprovalDate] [datetime] NULL,
[LastLoginDate] [datetime] NULL,
[IsLocked] [bit] NOT NULL,
[PasswordQuestion] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[PasswordAnswer] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[ActivationToken] [nvarchar](200) NULL,

CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUsers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
     CONSTRAINT [UX_User_EMail] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [EMail] ASC
),
 CONSTRAINT [UX_User_Login] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [Login] ASC
)
);

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_User_IsLocked]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IsLocked]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_User_EmailConfirmed]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [EmailConfirmed]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_User_PhoneNumberConfirmed]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [PhoneNumberConfirmed]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_User_TwoFactorEnabled]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [TwoFactorEnabled]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_User_LockoutEnabled]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [LockoutEnabled]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_User_AccessFailCount]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [AccessFailedCount]
GO

GO
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UserNameIndex]
    ON [dbo].[AspNetUsers]([UserName] ASC);
```

I've seen similar questions and there's a hint that there's a property called "Discriminator" but it's not described what it is and how should I declare it. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it doesn't work with pure sql querys.
You need to do the following to get it to work.
edit the web.config DefaultConnection string to point to the custom database (make sure you don't have the AspNet tables) 
Like this

Note I'm using "Datasource=." to make reference to my local db server.
after doing this build and run to register a new user. This will create the Identity framework database structure perfectly and all it's requirements on your custom database.
After this for example if you need to reference AspNetUsers table on another table. just modify your custom database.

Identity Framework uses it's own context. So you should add another context to run your Db if you are on Databasefirst approach. There might be better solutions for this issue (since you can't drag the models by just indicating the db connection string.) but this is the one that works for me! 
Good Luck!